# heredoc with subprocess.call not continuing to the next command

Tags: python

I'm running some linux commands but after the linux heredoc the next (df) command is not executing.

```
import subprocess

uci = "cav"

dse_db = "gtmgbldir=/cav/gtm/" + uci + "/" + uci + ".gld; \
            export gtmgbldir; \
            dse << EOF \
            dump -fileheader\n\
            EOF\n; \
            df; \
            "
subprocess.call(dse_db, shell=True)
```

Even more, if there is an error inside the heredod, it's not continuing at all.
I'm talking about an allert error of the "dsa" command.
Ofcourse if I'm runnning all the commands mannualy via the linux shell all is working.

Answer (score 1):

When you do line continuation using the backslash character (`\`), then there will be no real line break inserted. You can see this very easily if you put your string into the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> "foo \
bar \
baz"
'foo bar baz'
```

As you can see, the `\` allows you to break the lines but it will not produce a multiline string.

In order to have a multiline string, you should use triple quotes instead:

```
>>> '''foo
bar
baz'''
'foo\nbar\nbaz'
>>> """foo
bar
baz"""
'foo\nbar\nbaz'
```

Then, your heredoc string is valid and it will probably work.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I was asking, this is not the problerm.

Comment: I have several linux commands that I want to run and one of them is heredoc

Comment: My point is that you have no valid heredoc there, so the bash you try to execute is invalid to begin with. There are no line breaks in that string, so the heredoc never ends (because the terminating `EOF` needs to be on its own line) and as such, everything that follows is still part of the heredoc string.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast response but this will not solve my problem.

Comment: It does solve the problem that *“after the linux heredoc the next command is not executing”*. Please *try* it before you say that it doesn’t solve your problem. The missing new lines are the cause of your problem. Alternatively, add `\n` at the end of each line to insert new lines explicitely. And you can interrupt triple-quote strings in the same way you do single-quote strings: `'''foo''' + bar + '''baz'''`.

Comment: Also make sure that there is no whitespace before the terminating `EOF`. You currently have a lot of spaces because of the indentation there.

Comment: Yes, the white space was the problem, I already fix that, forget the triple quotes rule.